# Free C++ lib (Win32) to record microphone

Tags: c++, winapi, open-source, microphone

is there any recommendation for a library (c++, Win32, open source) to get the sound from a microphone?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try having a look at OpenAL[1] it might be overkill, but should be able to record from microphone as you wanted. There exists some pretty good articles about it on Gamedev.net[2] although I'm afraid none of them tells you how to record from a microphone. You should however be able to find the answer for that in the documentation. :) good luck,

---

[1] http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx

[2] http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article2008.asp

Comment: Just another link I found with OpenAL tutorials: http://www.devmaster.net/articles.php?catID=6

Answer (score 3):

[PortAudio - portable cross-platform Audio API](http://www.portaudio.com/)

> PortAudio provides a very simple API
>   for recording and/or playing sound
>   using a simple callback function.

Answer (score 2):

I found some code at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/RecordingAndMP3Encoding.aspx) (standard warning: Please review every bit of code you take from CodeProject carefully! It's useful, but I often find horrifying bugs in samples I get there!). That should give you a good clue as to the APIs and how to start using them. From there you can Google for references and related topics.

Answer (score 2):

- WaveInOpen - This is a function, that opens a wave input device.
- WaveInPrepareHeader - Prepare a record buffer with this function.
- WaveInAddBuffer - Adds a buffer to be recorded.
- WaveInStart - Used to
  start recording.
- WaveInClose - Closes a wave input device.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need cross platform, [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454%28VS.85%29.aspx) works well.  Although it is not open source, I believe you can distribute open source projects that require the DirectShow libraries.

Comment: Yeah, DirectX was my first choice, but I was looking which is OS. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You don't say that you need cross platform support, if cross platform support isn't necessary, I'd use the wave APIs or DirectSound - both are fairly straighforward to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the mci functions to record in the past. 
Sorry, this doesn't show making sure the microphone is selected as a recording input, but once its selected manually, it will stay unless somebody changes it. This was in a dialog, so thats what the windows handle came from.

```
#define ALIAS "mci_alias"

char mci_command[100];
char ReturnString[300];
int mci_error;

// open the device
sprintf(mci_command, "open new type waveaudio alias %s", ALIAS);
mci_err = mciSendString(mci_command, ReturnString, sizeof(ReturnString), m_hWnd);

// set the time format  
sprintf(mci_command,"set %s time format ms", ALIAS);    // just set time format
mci_err = mciSendString(mci_command, ReturnString, sizeof(ReturnString), m_hWnd);

// start the record. specify notifications with a MM_MCINOTIFY message)
sprintf(mci_command, "record %s notify", ALIAS);
mci_err = mciSendString(mci_command, ReturnString, sizeof(ReturnString), m_hWnd);

// wait for a stop button, or an error to occur

sprintf(mci_command,"stop %s", ALIAS);
mci_err = mciSendString(mci_command, ReturnString, sizeof(ReturnString), m_hWnd);

// save the file
sprintf(mci_command, "save %s %s", ALIAS, m_filename);
mci_err = mciSendString(mci_command, ReturnString, sizeof(ReturnString), m_hWnd);

sprintf(mci_command,"stop %s", ALIAS);
mci_err = mciSendString(mci_command, ReturnString, sizeof(ReturnString), m_hWnd);


// close the device
sprintf(mci_command,"close %s", ALIAS);
mci_err = mciSendString(mci_command, ReturnString, sizeof(ReturnString), m_hWnd);
```